# MySQL 5.6 replication causes 'waiting for table lock'

Tags: mysql, replication, locking

All of the sudden queries on slave server stopped with status `"Waiting for table level lock"`

I restart mysql service and stop replications and locking does not show up anymore. Once I turn replications back on I see huge increase in "waiting for table level lock" status for queries (`show full processlist`)

Replication is crucial for our situation and we can't keep it turned off.

What might cause this problem? Replication was running fine for last 5 months or so.

MySQL 5.6

Comment: @da_didi, it is a mix of innodb and myisam. We can't change myisam because the database is a part of 3rd party product. No triggers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that current replication thread is taking a lot of time updating a (big) change to a (big) table causing a long lock on the table. You may want to examine what the sql thread is trying to execute using `mysqlbinlog` with `--start-position` parameter. Hope this helps.